# Is DataGridView.DataSource synchronized with DataGridView UI?

Tags: c#, .net

assume we have a `DataGridView dgv` and `dgv.DataSource = dataTable` where
 `dataTable = new DataTable()`.

The question is: Is values we access through `dgv` like getting `dgv[i,j]` is always what we have in `dataTable` and vice versa ??

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: how can I be sure by doing it? you can not prove something just by experiencing it. maybe there is some case which is not appeared in my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes. If you take a look at the `DataGridViewCell.Value` property in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and follow its twisty path, you'll end up at some code that (after a bunch of noise to deal with the case of an unbound control) looks like this:

```
DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection dataConnection = dataGridView.DataConnection;
if (dataConnection == null)
{
    return null;
}
if (dataConnection.CurrencyManager.Count <= rowIndex)
{
    return this.Properties.GetObject(PropCellValue);
}
return dataConnection.GetValue(this.OwningColumn.BoundColumnIndex, this.ColumnIndex, rowIndex);
```

So here you can see that accessing the `Value` property of a `DataGridViewCell` is going straight to the data source. In other words it isn't some lagged synchronization process where you might have a value updated in the `DataGridView` *after* the corresponding row is updated in the `DataTable`; one just points straight to the other.